# Javascript atob base64 decode

Tags: javascript, base64

I am trying to send data using wget POST so I am using base64 to encode it to prevent misinterpretation of sent data. If I encode the data as is, scrambles text in several places. If I use sed and replace "/>" with ">" and "

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized it had cut off the question. I am substituting "slash greater than" and "less than slash" with just slashes on a server, encoding with base64, and then sending to another server via wget. It is successfully stored in a database on the second server, but when I try to retrieve it I get an error message that it is not a valid encoded string.